# Is there a way of listing the contents of the local directory in ftp?

Tags: ftp, ls

`lcd` changes local directories.

`ls` lists files on remote directory.

What I would like is `lls`, to list files on local directory.

Is this possible?

I know I can always open another terminal to do this, but I'm lazy!

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Yes:

`!dir`

The `!` tells the client to run a local shell command. Tested this using both the Windows and Fedora default ftp clients. Note that the actual command may depend upon your OS, for example `!ls` may be necessary on other versions of Unix/Linux.

---

For what it's worth, the `!` command is listed in the ftp client's help system:

> ```
> ftp> help !
> !               escape to the shell
> ```

Comment: No problem, glad to help :). Actually picked up the idea from vim, which uses `!` to run local shell commands.

Comment: If you are using Apple's bash shell (or similar versions), you'll need to use `!ls` instead of `!dir`.

Comment: Good point, on a *nix system, `ls` would be the proper command. Just depends what OS you are running your ftp client on...

Comment: I'm used to use `lls` in other FTP clients. So I've created an alias like this in `~/.config/lftp/rc`: `alias lls ls -alh`.

Answer (score 7):

To list files locally use following command

```
!dir
```

Or use following command

```
!ls
```

> ***Note:*** **!** means locally not the remote.

**lcd** is working but **!cd** will not work and **lpwd** is not working but **!pwd** is working.